# How does the Flink SQL Client distinguish batch mode and stream mode?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

As we all know, Flink has two core APIs (DataStream/DataSet), but when I use flink Sql Client to submit a job, I do not need to choose the stream or batch mode.So how Flink SQL Client decide to use batch mode and stream mode. I did not find the answer in the Official document.
So, I would like to know how Flink SQL Client to distinguish batch mode and stream mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Flink's SQL client you can specify the environment to be used via

```
sql-client.sh embedded -d <default environment file> -e <session environment file>
```

An environment file is a YAML file describing the catalog and table execution environment, including whether to use batch or streaming:

```
execution:
  type: streaming
```

See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sqlClient.html#environment-files) for more details.